# Getting the response from pairDevice()

Tags: java, android

I pair device and I want to in my activity get a response of this function

```
 private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(DeviceListActivity.this, "Nie udalo się sparować urządzenia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the question and the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register BroadcastReceiver.

```
BroadcastReceiver mBondStateBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if(intent.getAction() == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED) {
              // do your stuff
         }
      }
    };

final IntentFilter bondFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(mBondStateBroadcastReceiver, bondFilter);
```